# MFC: CListView's CListCtrl::InsertItem(0, "test", imageindex) shows up at end of list not beginning?

Tags: winapi, mfc, clistctrl, clistview

I have a `CListView` created via:

```
return CListView::Create(lpszClassName,
                         _T("ListView"),
                         dwStyle | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_ALIGNTOP | LVS_ICON | LVS_AUTOARRANGE,
                         rect,
                         pParentWnd,
                         nID,
                         pContext);
```

It displays the graphics of an attached `CImageList` and has a text string under it.

In the past I've always just added items to the end of the list view and it shows up there.  Today, I decided to insert the list view item to the first location instead, but it's still showing up at the end of the list view?

I insert the item via:

```
int debug=listctrl.InsertItem(0, mytexstring, imageindex);
```

The `imageindex` is at the end of the `CImageList` and the image added after adding the call above (why after instead of before, not sure, but that's how it is).  debug comes back 0.

Once I do that, the new item is showing at the end of the list view and even scrolls the screen there when the list has a lot of items.

Shouldn't inserting the list view item to index 0 make it show up at the start?

What am I missing or doing wrong?

TIA!!

UPDATE:

If I do this:

```
listctrl.SetView(LV_VIEW_LIST);
listctrl.SetView(LV_VIEW_ICON);
```

It will work, but I don't think I should I have to do that?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you remove the `LVS_AUTOARRANGE` style?

Comment: Yes, same issue.  I tried listctrl.SetItemPosition(0, pt) where pt is 0,0 but didn't do anything either (but may not work in vista or later, this is latest win10 version).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added an update to the original message.  Don't think I should have to do that?

Comment: What's `dwStyle`?

Comment: It comes from the Create() function (the class is derived from CListView for some other addition functions).  That would come from the CSplitterWnd::CreateView(), which is created via the CMainFrame::OnCreateClient().  The value is 0x50000000

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `| LVS_NOSORTHEADER` to the style to get the item inserted at the right place. I think this affects the default sorting behavior.

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't; all it does is stop you being able to click on the header items as if they were buttons (which then generates notification messages that you can respond to by resorting the list).

Comment: It didn't change anything.  My work around seems to work, so unless someone has the answer that works without the work around, I'll just use it, no side effects from it.

Comment: Ah, I missed LVS_ICON. I had LVS_REPORT in mind. Maybe this example can help you with the sort order: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27774/CListCtrl-and-sorting-rows -- but I'm not sure if/how it applies to LVS_ICON ListCtrls...